# Add Contact in Android 1.6

Tags: android, android-contacts, android-contentprovider

I am trying to add contact(Name,Phone Number, Note, Email ID) in Android 1.6 but I am unable to do so because Android 1.6 does not supports ContactsContract/ContentProviderOperation etc's. I searched lot on web but found all the example above Android 1.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Nick I found the solution Thanks for your help Here is some code snippet to retrieve Email from the Contacts in Android 1.6

```
    String[] PROJECTION = new String[] { Contacts.ContactMethods._ID,
            Contacts.ContactMethods.DATA, Contacts.PeopleColumns.NAME };
    c = managedQuery(Contacts.ContactMethods.CONTENT_EMAIL_URI, PROJECTION,
            null, null, Contacts.ContactMethods.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER);
```

Answer (score 0):

The Contacts API didn't come in to being until Android 2.0.  You will have to develop your application against a 2.0+ SDK if you want to use this API.

Source:
http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/contacts.html

Comment: But my Requirement is on Android 1.6 I can't switch to 2.0+ now.

Comment: Well your application can't use APIs that don't exist.  Either increase to 2.0+ or don't use Contacts.  You can't have both.